# How to change permalink structure and keep permalinks for old posts

Tags: permalinks, migration, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating to WP from blogger and my old permalinks have the structure:   `/year/month/postname.html`

In wp for my future posts on I would like to use the `/postname.html` custom structure.

I don't want to redirect the address of the old posts to the new permalink structure, because old posts have quite a few inbound links and I don't want to lose any "link juice". Instead I would like to keep the old permalinks for the old posts.

I believe this could be achieved using some mod_rewrite rules. Since all my old post permalinks start with the year number (/2010/... or /2011/... or /2012/... or /2013/... or /2014/... or /2015/...) I wonder which would be the most efficient way to write the mod_rewrite. (instead of writing a rule for each post)

*idea:* could that be solved by adding/creating a custom post type and use the rewrite argument to define the permalink structure? (what would be the code for it?)

Comment: Making a 301 redirection is the best (and easiest) solution from my point of view. Can you explain why you don't want to make a redirect?

Comment: That would be good for consistency too. However, old posts have inbound links and don't want to lose any "link juice" with the 301s, for seo reasons.

Comment: You won't loose any inbound links, 301 from old to new url structure is the way to go when migrating.

Comment: That is the point. Making a 301 redirection will transfer all the ranking and link juice.